# How to perform some operation based on SQL return code I am using spring data JPA

Tags: java, db2, spring-data-jpa

I am working on some project where I used spring data jpa to query against DB2. Suppose used query "Select a,b from sometable where a='XX' ". So now based on sql code I want to perform some operation but how I will get sql return code as I am using spring data JPA.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "sql return code".

Comment: Actually I am from mainframe background , so suppose we are executing some query in cobol then db2 query will return SQL Return Code and this held in the field SQLCODE . Now we can check if SQLCODE = 0 or SQLCODE =100 etc.. and based on this we do some operation. So I wangt to know if same is possible by using spring data JPA?

Comment: What does this sql code represents. When you execute a query, it returns a list of data, or throws an exception if the query couldn't be executed. The list of data is all you need: it contains the data you selected. What would a sql code be useful for?

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far. Using Spring data you can simply make a method query i.e.: `List<SomeTable> findByAContaining(String a);` This however needs some support classes. I suggest checking a Spring Data JPA tutorial, or maybe even Java as this does not appear your common language?

Comment: @JBNizet sql code represent integer number if its returning negative int meaning sql did not executed correctly , if +ve int means some warring but ok and if 0 means every thing is fine. Just for example suppose we are getting 100 as a return code means data not found. I am talking w.r.t DB2 return code.

Comment: JPA works at a much higher level, and uses Java's principle: if the query returns a list, then all went fine, and the data that the query was supposed to select is in the list. If something is wrong, then an exception is thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet so you mean to say there will be only three case ,first we will get data ,second  will not get data and third will get exception? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If there is an error executing the query, you'll get an exception. If the query executes, its results will be in the returned list. If the query returns nothing, the list will be empty.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet is there any alternate in java to full fill my requirement? Why I'm asking this because its possible to get sql return code when we use java stored procedure.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense. Your sql return code is an implementation detail of your COBOL API. Java is not COBOL. It doesn't use the same API. But it allows checking if the query executed correctly, and it allows knowing what the query returned. I don't understand what else you would need. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I got the point . Thanks :)